# How to remove matching subelement attribute of .xml file?

Tags: python, xml

```xml
<DocRoot />
  <Root />
    <Comment />
    <Point PointName="Point1">
      </Depth_Profile>
    </Point>
    <Point PointName="Remove">
      </Depth_Profile>
    </Point>
  </Root>
</DocRoot>
```

How do I remove `Point` nodes with the attribute `PointName=Remove`?

Comment: XML is not correct

Answer (score 1):

First of all your xml format needs to be fixed and then use the below code

test.xml

```
  <DocRoot>
    <Root>
        <Comment />
        <Point PointName="Point1">
          <Depth_Profile />
        </Point>
        <Point PointName="Remove">
          <Depth_Profile />
        </Point>
    </Root>
  </DocRoot>
```

Python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

dict = {}
for parent in tree.iter():
    for child in parent:            
        if 'PointName' in child.attrib:
                   if child.attrib['PointName'] == 'Remove':
                           dict[child] = parent

for child in dict:
    parent = dict[child]
    parent.remove(child)
    tree.write('test.xml')
```

Comment: @compdoc it will be very nice if you accept my answer